# Effect work only in the simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, audio

I use the code below to play the laser ship sound, but it only works in the simulator.  Why?

the code :

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"Laser_ship.caf"];
```

then

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"Laser_ship.caf" pitch:1.0f pan:0.0f gain:0.25f];
```

also I use about 8 effect sounds that all work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the case of your filename correct? The simulator is case insensitive but the device isn't :)

i.e. you have `@"Laser_ship.caf"`, is it really called `@"laser_ship.caf"`

Comment: Awesome Thank you Very much I have 2 versions of the sounds (mp4 and caf) this is the only one has deference in the name.

Comment: No problem - I run into this all the time!